# Getting the resource path during testing

Tags: swift, swift4

I am trying to write a unit tests that uses a file in my project. In my application, I use `FileManager.default.currentDirectoryPath` to get the path to my file. However, the test path is different when I use the same in tesing. After reading up the documentation I understood that XCode uses a different path for unit testing.

I was wondering how I can get the correct Bundle path for `File.txt` in my tests

I have tried this but it returns null

```
let testBundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
let fileURL = testBundle.url(forResource: "File", withExtension: "txt")
```

The following is my directory structure. ShopTests is my unit test file and File.txt is the file for which I am trying to retrieve the path url for(both highlighted in picture)
[image]

Comment: try `Bundle.main.url(forResource: "File", withExtension: "txt")`

Comment: it returns nil.

Comment: When you add it to your project make sure you select copy to project. Also go to your Target Build Phases and check if your file it is listed in Copy Bundle Resources

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I am doing it in a test that works:

```
let dataURL = Bundle(for: TripBuilderTest.self).url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "json")
```

I think I remember having had the same problem you are reporting. Try using classname.self as per above.

Comment: The Bundle( For , Should it be the module name or the testFile name ?I tried the test file and it returns nul.     let dataURL = Bundle(for: ShopTests.self).url(forResource: "File", withExtension: "txt").

Comment: Wait I think I know what your problem is. Show me all your code.

Comment: I think maybe you are attempting to create it in the top of the test? at which time the test has not yet been constructed, hence the null. Please show the complete source file. In mine, I am getting the file inside the test itself, though I am sure you could call it inside setup as well.

Comment: I used it in the tests function. Did not use it in the Setup() method. So would that be the problem. ? Hold on I will share the code online

Comment: Did you look to make sure that the file is being copied in the Copy Bundle Resources for the TEST target build?

Comment: I confirm this is working. Seems like the `main` bundle cannot be a test target.